# How to test PHP and MySQL memory when it is running?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache

I have the following simple script which will create a database with several tables, and populate them with all the zipcodes in the USA.  I've included the script and sql file, however, I am not asking anyone to review the scripts, but included it for reference.

It used to take about 90 seconds to run on my remote VPS and it still takes about 90 seconds on my development box at home.

All of a sudden, it now takes virtually forever on my VPS.

The two servers have almost identical configuration except the VPS is running mysql5.1.71 and the home box is running mysql5.5.

How can I see how much memory is being used real-time by PHP and MySQL?

EDIT.  Top screenshot is attached:

[image]

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
set_time_limit(2000);
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test_database;charset=utf8",'xxx','xxx',array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES=>false,PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY=>true,PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE=>PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

syslog(LOG_INFO,'Start');
$time1=microtime(true);
shell_exec("mysql -xxx-xxx-hlocalhost -Dtest_database < test_database.sql");
$time2=microtime(true);
$time=$time2-$time1;
echo($time.'<br>');
syslog(LOG_INFO,'Database Built: '.$time);

$file = fopen('zipcodes.csv', "r");

$sql ='INSERT INTO cities (id, name, states_id) VALUES (NULL,?,?)';
$stmt_cities = $conn->prepare($sql);
$sql ='INSERT INTO counties (id, name) VALUES (NULL,?)';
$stmt_counties = $conn->prepare($sql);
$sql ='INSERT INTO zipcodes (id, latitude, longitude, zipcode_types_id, timezones_id, counties_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)';
$stmt_zipcodes = $conn->prepare($sql);
$sql ='INSERT INTO cities_has_zipcodes (cities_id, zipcodes_id) VALUES (?,?)';
$stmt_zipcodes_cross = $conn->prepare($sql);
$sql ='SELECT co.id FROM counties AS co INNER JOIN zipcodes AS z ON co.id=z.counties_id INNER JOIN cities_has_zipcodes AS chz ON chz.zipcodes_id=z.id INNER JOIN cities AS c ON c.id=chz.cities_id WHERE co.name=? AND c.states_id=?';
$stmt_check_county = $conn->prepare($sql);
$sql ='SELECT id FROM cities WHERE name=? AND states_id=?';
$stmt_check_city = $conn->prepare($sql);

while (($data = fgetcsv($file, 100000, ",")) !== FALSE)
{
    //See if a county of a given name has already been inserted for given state
    $stmt_check_county->execute(array($data[5],$data[4]));
    if(!$county_id=$stmt_check_county->fetchColumn())
    {
        $stmt_counties->execute(array($data[5]));
        $county_id=$conn->lastInsertId();
    }
    //See if a city of a given name has already been inserted for given state
    $stmt_check_city->execute(array($data[3],$data[4]));
    if(!$cities_id=$stmt_check_city->fetchColumn())
    {
        $stmt_cities->execute(array($data[3],$data[4]));
        $cities_id=$conn->lastInsertId();
    }
    $stmt_zipcodes->execute(array(sprintf("%05d",$data[0]),$data[1],$data[2],$data[6],$data[7],$county_id));
    $stmt_zipcodes_cross->execute(array($cities_id,sprintf("%05d",$data[0])));
}

fclose($file);

$time3=microtime(true);
$time=$time3-$time2;
echo($time.'<br>');
syslog(LOG_INFO,'Done: '.$time);
```

test_database.sql

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS test_database; CREATE DATABASE test_database; USE test_database;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS states (   id CHAR(2) NOT NULL ,   name VARCHAR(45) NULL ,   PRIMARY KEY (id) ) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cities (   id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,   name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,   states_id CHAR(2) NOT NULL ,   PRIMARY KEY (id) ,   INDEX fk_zipcodes_states1_idx (states_id ASC) ,   UNIQUE INDEX makeUnique (states_id ASC, name ASC) ,   CONSTRAINT fk_zipcodes_states1
    FOREIGN KEY (states_id )
    REFERENCES states (id )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION) ENGINE = InnoDB PACK_KEYS = 0 ROW_FORMAT = DEFAULT;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS zipcode_types (   id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,   name VARCHAR(45) NULL ,   PRIMARY KEY (id) ) ENGINE
= InnoDB PACK_KEYS = 0 ROW_FORMAT = DEFAULT;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS counties (   id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,   name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,   PRIMARY KEY (id) ) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS timezones (   id CHAR(4) NOT NULL ,   name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,   PRIMARY KEY (id) ) ENGINE = InnoDB PACK_KEYS
= 0 ROW_FORMAT = DEFAULT;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS zipcodes (   id CHAR(5) NOT NULL ,   longitude DECIMAL(9,6) NOT NULL ,   latitude DECIMAL(9,6) NOT NULL ,   zipcode_types_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,   counties_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,   timezones_id CHAR(4) NOT NULL ,   PRIMARY KEY (id) ,   INDEX fk_zipcodes_zipcode_types1_idx (zipcode_types_id ASC) ,   INDEX fk_zipcodes_counties1_idx (counties_id ASC) ,   INDEX fk_zipcodes_timezones1_idx (timezones_id ASC) ,   CONSTRAINT fk_zipcodes_zipcode_types1
    FOREIGN KEY (zipcode_types_id )
    REFERENCES zipcode_types (id )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,   CONSTRAINT fk_zipcodes_counties1
    FOREIGN KEY (counties_id )
    REFERENCES counties (id )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,   CONSTRAINT fk_zipcodes_timezones1
    FOREIGN KEY (timezones_id )
    REFERENCES timezones (id )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cities_has_zipcodes (   cities_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,   zipcodes_id CHAR(5) NOT NULL ,   PRIMARY KEY (cities_id, zipcodes_id) ,   INDEX fk_cities_has_zipcodes_zipcodes1_idx (zipcodes_id ASC) ,   INDEX fk_cities_has_zipcodes_cities1_idx (cities_id ASC) ,   CONSTRAINT fk_cities_has_zipcodes_cities1
    FOREIGN KEY (cities_id )
    REFERENCES cities (id )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,   CONSTRAINT fk_cities_has_zipcodes_zipcodes1
    FOREIGN KEY (zipcodes_id )
    REFERENCES zipcodes (id )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION) ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO zipcode_types (id, name) VALUES (1,'Standard'); INSERT INTO zipcode_types (id, name) VALUES (2,'PO Box Only'); INSERT INTO zipcode_types (id, name) VALUES (3,'Military'); INSERT INTO zipcode_types (id, name) VALUES (4,'Unique');

INSERT INTO timezones (id, name) VALUES ('HAST','Hawaii-Aleutian Standard Time'); INSERT INTO timezones (id, name) VALUES ('AKST','Alaska Standard Time'); INSERT INTO timezones (id, name) VALUES ('PST','Pacific Standard Time'); INSERT INTO timezones (id, name) VALUES ('MST','Mountain Standard Time'); INSERT INTO timezones (id, name) VALUES ('CST','Central Standard Time'); INSERT INTO timezones (id, name) VALUES ('EST','Eastern Standard Time'); INSERT INTO timezones (id, name) VALUES ('AST','Atlantic Standard Time'); INSERT INTO timezones (id, name) VALUES ('XXX','Unknown');

INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('AL','ALABAMA'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('AK','ALASKA'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('AS','AMERICAN SAMOA'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('AZ','ARIZONA'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('AR','ARKANSAS'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('CA','CALIFORNIA'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('CO','COLORADO'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('CT','CONNECTICUT'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('DE','DELAWARE'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('DC','DISTRICT OF COLUMBIA'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('FM','FEDERATED STATES OF MICRONESIA'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('FL','FLORIDA'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('GA','GEORGIA'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('GU','GUAM'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('HI','HAWAII'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('ID','IDAHO'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('IL','ILLINOIS'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('IN','INDIANA'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('IA','IOWA'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('KS','KANSAS'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('KY','KENTUCKY'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('LA','LOUISIANA'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('ME','MAINE'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('MH','MARSHALL ISLANDS'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('MD','MARYLAND'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('MA','MASSACHUSETTS'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('MI','MICHIGAN'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('MN','MINNESOTA'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('MS','MISSISSIPPI'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('MO','MISSOURI'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('MT','MONTANA'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('NE','NEBRASKA'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('NV','NEVADA'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('NH','NEW HAMPSHIRE'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('NJ','NEW JERSEY'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('NM','NEW MEXICO'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('NY','NEW YORK'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('NC','NORTH CAROLINA'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('ND','NORTH DAKOTA'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('MP','NORTHERN MARIANA ISLANDS'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('OH','OHIO'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('OK','OKLAHOMA'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('OR','OREGON'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('PW','PALAU'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('PA','PENNSYLVANIA'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('PR','PUERTO RICO'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('RI','RHODE ISLAND'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('SC','SOUTH CAROLINA'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('SD','SOUTH DAKOTA'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('TN','TENNESSEE'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('TX','TEXAS'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('UT','UTAH'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('VT','VERMONT'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('VI','VIRGIN ISLANDS'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('VA','VIRGINIA'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('WA','WASHINGTON'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('WV','WEST VIRGINIA'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('WI','WISCONSIN'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('WY','WYOMING'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('AA','AA UNKNOWN'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('AE','AE UNKNOWN'); INSERT INTO states (id,name) VALUES ('AP','AP UNKNOWN');
```

Comment: "virtually forever" means it never finishes?

Comment: @Pekka웃  Been 30 minutes, and still not finished.  Looks like it is populating about 10 records a second which will take about 1 hour (compared to what used to take 90 seconds).

Comment: top command in linux might help

Comment: @Undefined_variable.  I attached a screenshot.  Does anything standout?  Thanks.  Edit 1. On further review, 99% CPU use by MySQL stands out!  Why?  Edit 2.  And no free memory!  Why?

Comment: @Undefined_variable.  Evidently, I have memory.  Tried to edit my comment and remove my statement that I don't but it was too late.